# Can I use the context as @context inside an interactor class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, interactors, interactor-backend

In some interactors, several functions are defined to be used in call function (I'm not using utility for organize such functions).
Is it fine to use `@context` instead of `context` in this situation? 
Ref URL: https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor 
Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you give some examples? Do you meant to create affectional methods in class? Not to have only ```call``` method?

Comment: In [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max)'s answer, it seems fine to have additional methods inside the interactor.

Comment: It is better to have only private.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I'd love to hear you. Thank you `denys281`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the source code `context` is just a simple accessor (getter method) declared by `attr_reader`:

```
module Interactor
  # Internal: Install Interactor's behavior in the given class.
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      extend ClassMethods
      include Hooks

      # Public: Gets the Interactor::Context of the Interactor instance.
      attr_reader :context
    end
  end
```

There is thus almost no discernible difference between accessing the instance variable directly (`@context`) and through the `context` method as long as you're accessing it from within the class that includes this module.

```
class MyInteractor
  include Interactor

  def my_method
    @context
    # is the exact same as 
    context
    # except for the method call
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!